# Firebase Analytics setScreenName deprecated

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

In version 6.29.0 of Firebase Analytics the method

`class func setScreenName(_ screenName: String?, screenClass screenClassOverride: String?)`

is deprecated. The hint given is to **Use +[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:kFIREventScreenView parameters:] instead.**

My question is what is the parameter for screenName? How do I rewrite my helper method:

```
import FirebaseAnalytics
func setScreenName(_ screenName: String) {
    Analytics.setScreenName(screenName, screenClass: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

This is the code to rewrite the deprecated method:

Replace this line:

```swift
Analytics.setScreenName(screenName, screenClass: nil)
```

With this line:

```swift
Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventScreenView, parameters: [AnalyticsParameterScreenName: screenName])
```

Comment: Ah, I missed the AnalyticsParameterScreenName part. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, sorry to ask this question but since you manually log the event (in your answer), isn't there a problem of data duplication due to Firebase automatic event collect. Screen views won't be logged twice?

Comment: @Laura, I have tried this but I am getting following error, Can you help us https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65843488/use-of-unresolved-identifier-analyticseventscreenview-in-swift-firebase-analyt

Comment: Hi @Laura I tried your suggestions, But I am getting following errors Use of unresolved identifier 'AnalyticsEventScreenView'
Use of unresolved identifier 'AnalyticsParameterScreenName'
Even I am using latest version of analytics from firebase using pods, Any suggestions?

Comment: Which file do we replace this in?

Comment: @MavBzh you should place it in viewDidAppear, if you don't, Firebase (used to) automatically send it, with a "not set" screen name. Perhaps they changed it recently

Comment: @AnilkumariOS-ReactNative you probably need to import FirebaseAnalytics in this file, or use "kFIRParameterScreenName".

Answer (score 30):

I did it in this way:

Deprecated code

```
Analytics.setScreenName(name, screenClass: className)
```

new code

```
Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventScreenView, parameters: [AnalyticsParameterScreenName: name,
                                                          AnalyticsParameterScreenClass: className])
```

Comment: I tried this but, for me showing following error Use of unresolved identifier 'AnalyticsEventScreenView'
Use of unresolved identifier 'AnalyticsParameterScreenName'
Any Suggestions?

Comment: will this not create the event twice?

Comment: Although this code will fire the same event, its not a good replacement for the old event. 

Old method also handled the  "engagement_time" parameter internally. Do you know how to do with the new method?

Answer (score 24):

Just in case it can help someone, here is the Objective-C version:

```
[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:kFIREventScreenView parameters: @{kFIRParameterScreenName: screenName}];
```

Comment: You can also add `kFIRParameterScreenClass` to your parameters to replace `screenClass`.

Answer (score 15):

Here is the Android version:

### Java

```java
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_NAME, screenName);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_CLASS, screenClass);
bundle.putString(MyAppAnalyticsConstants.Param.TOPIC, topic);
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SCREEN_VIEW, bundle);
```

### Kotlin

```kotlin
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_NAME, screenName)
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_CLASS,classname)
firebase.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SCREEN_VIEW, bundle)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
extension Analytics
{
    static func setScreenName(_ screenName:String, screenClass:String)
    {
        Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventScreenView, parameters: [AnalyticsParameterScreenName: screenName,AnalyticsParameterScreenClass:screenClass])
    }
}
```

Simple add this extension in your project no need to change anything after this