# Use of unresolved identifier 'AnalyticsEventScreenView' in Swift Firebase Analytics

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am working on iOS application and for tracking user events I am using Firebase analytics. I have installed it by pod

```
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
```

But for tracking events I am getting them by following code

```
            Analytics.logEvent("Sign_up_tapped", parameters:["SCREEN_NAME":"SIGN UP"])
```

But, I am trying to get screen name/View/Class.
So, I have tried following code, But throwing compile errors

```
            Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventScreenView, parameters: [AnalyticsParameterScreenName: "Signup Screen",
            AnalyticsParameterScreenClass: "Signup view"])
```

Errors are below

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'AnalyticsEventScreenView'
Use of unresolved identifier 'AnalyticsParameterScreenName'
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews#swift

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: What version of FirebaseAnalytics are you using? You might have to upgrade

Comment: Installing FirebaseAnalytics (6.5.0)
this is the version it was showing while installing @NicolasElPapu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried `pod update Firebase/Analytics`, Also `pod update FirebaseAnalytics` but, both not get updated versions.

So, Finally did `pod update` in terminal, And it is get updated version of Firebase Analytics and then issue resolved.